# $a;b;c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $abc=1$. Prove : $P=\frac{ab}{2b+c}+\frac{bc}{2c+a}+\frac{ca}{2a+b}\geq 1$

Tags: inequality

$a;b;c\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $abc=1$. Prove : $P=\frac{ab}{2b+c}+\frac{bc}{2c+a}+\frac{ca}{2a+b}\geq 1$

Thanks :)

I have proved that : $P=\sum \frac{ab}{2b+c}\Rightarrow P=\sum \frac{1}{2bc+c^{2}}$

Use Cauchy-Schwarz :
$\Rightarrow P=\sum \frac{1}{2bc+c^{2}}\geq \frac{(1+1+1)^{2}}{(a+b+c)^{2}}=\frac{9}{(a+b+c)^{2}}$

But : $a+b+c\geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}=3\Rightarrow (a+b+c)^{2}\geq 9\Rightarrow \frac{9}{(a+b+c)^{2}}\leq 1$

!?

Comment: I am not sure how you applied the C-S inequality.  If you applied it correctly, then it is just not a good enough estimate.

Answer (score 6):

let $$a=\dfrac{z}{y},b=\dfrac{x}{z},c=\dfrac{y}{x}$$

then
$$\dfrac{ab}{2b+c}=\dfrac{x^2z}{2x^2y+y^2z}$$
so Use cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$\left(\dfrac{x^2z}{2x^2y+y^2z}+\dfrac{y^2x}{2y^2z+z^2x}+\dfrac{z^2y}{2z^2x+x^2y}\right)(z(2x^2y+y^2z)+x(2y^2z+z^2x^2)+y(2z^2x+x^2y))\ge (xz+yx+zy)^2$$
it suffices to prove that
$$\dfrac{(xy+yz+xz)^2}{(z(2x^2y+y^2z)+x(2y^2z+z^2x^2)+y(2z^2x+x^2y))}\ge 1$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (xy+yz+xz)^2\ge (z(2x^2y+y^2z)+x(2y^2z+z^2x^2)+y(2z^2x+x^2y))$$
since $$(z(2x^2y+y^2z)+x(2y^2z+z^2x^2)+y(2z^2x+x^2y))=2xyz(x+y+z)+(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2)$$
it's obvious is true.

Comment: Nice proof with application of C-S ineqaulity! +1

Answer (score 0):

Although someone has already answered, I did work out this proof for the special case of a = 1 and wanted to post it.

X = (ab)/(2b+c)  Y = (bc)/(2c+a)  Z = (ca)/(2a+b)  abc = 1. P = X + Y + Z.  Show that P $\ge$ 1.
Let a = 1, b>1, c = 1/b = $b^{-1}$

X= b/(2b + $b^{-1}$) =  b $^2$/(b $^2$ +1)
Y = 1/(2$b^{-1}$ + 1) = b/(b + 2)
Z = $b^{-1}$/(2 + b) = 1/(b(b + 2)

X and Y  are both < 1  and monotonically increasing if b > 1, with limit 1 as b $\rightarrow \infty$.  So for B large enough  X + Y > 1.

Z is decreasing to 0 as b gets large, but is not needed to get P > 1 if b is large.
If a = b = c = 1 the X = Y = Z = 1/3 so that P = 1.

So if P is monotonically increasing on (1, $\infty$) then P > 1 always.
A simple but tedious computation shows that dP/db > 0 for all b$\ge 1$.  So P is increasing from that minimum value and must always be > 1 for any b > 1.

Insofar as someone has already provided a complete solution, I won't work out the general case.

Answer (score 0):

We have $ P = \sum \frac{(ab)^2}{2ab^2 + abc} \geq \frac{(\sum ab)^2 } {\sum 2ab^2 + abc }  $ by CS. RTS

$$ (\sum \frac{1}{c} ) ^2  = (\sum ab)^2 \geq 3abc + \sum 2ab^2$$

Expanding, and using $ abc = 1$, RTS

$$\sum \frac{ bc}{a} + \sum 2a \geq 3 + 2 (\sum \frac{b}{c} ). $$

This is true because we can sum up:

- $\frac{bc}{a} + b \geq 2 \frac{c}{a}  $ (and cyclic inequalities)
- $\sum a \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{abc} = 3 $